# Create a copy of a DB that is blank then import data from another DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, compare

I have 2 databases I need to work with.

- Database A (DBA) = the clients database that is far too outdated to be used with my current data structure.
- Database B (DBB) = my current development database

What I need, is to find a way to create a blank database that is structured as DBB, schemas, tables, triggers, everything, and then import data from DBA.

I have the Red Gate SQL Compare/Datacompare and SQL Management Tool available to me.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible with what I have or possible in general?

Normally I have scripts to update the DB going up a version at a time, but DBA is so far behind on the updates, I do not have access to those scripts anymore.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RedGate stuff but you could do the Generate Scripts task (right click a database in SSMS) on both.  Select Schema Only for DBA then Data Only for DBB in the Advanced Options.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I just took a different approach. Restored a new DB using DBB as the source, and then just deleted all the data from all the tables.